# Making the "Select a file to preview" pane disappear in Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer

How do I make it go away? It's always locking my files just because I have the damn file clicked!

It's in the file explorer.

Comment: Oh come on!  There has to be a way to do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it, in your explorer window out go to Tools->Folder Options->General and select the "Use Windows classic folders" radio button.

Answer (score 2):

There is a little icon in the top right hand corner which says "show the preview pane" when you hover the mouse over it. Click it to disable preview pane.